# Ideal Integrator Magnitude Response

Tags: control

[image]

I was reading this signals and systems book and saw this frequency response plot for an ideal integrator. The phase plot makes sense to me but the magnitude response. **I thought an ideal integrator is a pole at the origin and so the graph should start off with a -20dB/dec. This seems to be something different?**

Comment: The graph may not be log scale. There are no labels on the axis. So you can assume that it is drawn in normal scale amd not log scale. The graph looks like an ordinary plot f 1/s.

Comment: @AJN Ah! That makes a lot of sense now. I'm so used to seeing log scales for these that I completely forgot.

Comment: @AJN IMHO a book that mixes log and linear plots like that should be read with caution.

Comment: Why do you say "mixes"? The differentiator plot? That would be linear graph in linear scale as s well as log scale????

Comment: It's 'Linear Systems and Signals' by Lathi and Green if you were wondering.

Comment: Replot fig 3 on a log scale

Comment: @AJN Yes, I'm talking about consistency. If you present three plots side by side representing the basics, don't mix linear and logarithmic because it just confuses the people that are getting in contact with such notions for the very first time. Also, I was not pointing the finger at you, but at the book/authors (not sure if that's how you perceived my comment, that's why I'm saying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot looks like a plot of 1/w when plotted in linear scale (x as well as y axis).

Straight line occurs when both axes are in log scale.